# Should I embed XCFramework (third-party) in a Xcode project?

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

I found that the project would fail to build (error:image not loaded) if the normal third-party framework does't set as "embedded" in the project settings.
However, this time, I rebuilt this third-party framework as XCFramework, and everything goes fine with "Do Not Embed" settings for XCFramework.

Should I embed XCFramework or not?

Comment: It seems that it has sth. to do with "debug" mode. While debugging in the simulator, Xcode would load all frameworks needed even if they're set as "Do Not Embed". However, if you directly run app or debug in the real device, "image not load" would occur for those frameworks set as "Do Not Embed". So, we should embed all third-party frameworks I think.

Answer (score 11):

Select `"Embed & Sign"` to avoid `image not found` crash when running apps on physical device which contains any third-party XCFrameworks.

This option can be selected from linked xcframework under `Targets -> General -> Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content`.

[image]

But the application with xcframework will work fine in simulator with any of options available from `Do Not Embed`, `Embed & Sign` or `Embed Without Signing`.

Comment: Also highlight all, switch one and the rest will follow. I saved you all less time than I spent writing this.